# Is Jetty9's graceful shutdown broken?

Tags: jetty

It looks Server#setGracefulShutdown is changed to Server#setStopTimeout from Jetty9. But it doesn't look to behave in the same way.
It doesn't look Jetty9 doesn't wait for requests to complete before it shuts down.

Here is tests which stops jetty server while it's processing requests:

With Jetty 8.1.13.v20130916, test passes: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6930013

With Jetty 9.0.6.v20130930, test fails: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6930002

The only difference is "Server#setGracefulShutdown" and "Server#setStopTimeout".
Am I missing something?

Comment: File a bug at [RT/Jetty on Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jetty&format=guided)

Comment: Thanks, created https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420142

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be broken again in 9.2.1: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439067